# how to order the button

Tags: css, material-ui

I am using material-ui and I am stuck here. I am trying to create a homepage of a dashboard with the services listed.
I am trying to align these 6 buttons, with 2 rows and 3 columns with a total of 6 buttons. I am new to grid logic so I am sorry. How can I achieve this ?. thank you
[image]

Basically I am trying to force it like that on all screen beside on mobile.
[image]
here is my code :

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: '300px',

},

}));

export default function Menu() {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={3}>
                <Button
                    style={{ width: '300px', padding: '60px', margin: '15px' }}
                    variant='contained' color='Default'>
                    <AddIcon />Study
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={3}>
                <Button
                    style={{ width: '300px', padding: '60px', margin: '15px' }}
                    variant='contained' color='Default'>
                    <AddIcon />All Studies
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={3}>
                <Button
                    style={{ width: '300px', padding: '60px', margin: '15px' }}
                    variant='contained' color='Default'>
                    <AddIcon />Planning
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={3}>
                <Button
                    style={{ width: '300px', padding: '60px', margin: '15px' }}
                    variant='contained' color='Default'>
                    <AddIcon />Products
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={3}>
                <Button
                    style={{ width: '300px', padding: '60px', margin: '15px' }}
                    variant='contained' color='Default'>
                    <AddIcon />Platform
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={3}>
                <Button
                    style={{ width: '300px', padding: '60px', margin: '15px' }}
                    variant='contained' color='Default'>
                    <AddIcon />Clients
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a grid with 2 rows and 3 columns? In that case a CSS Grid might be the easier solution. You could also use `flex-wrap` to force the flex items to wrap to the next line.

Comment: You probably need separate container element like  `div` for each row of buttons.

Comment: Thank you Kodoko, I followed your advice and I did use the grid. You can check the code, i updated it, I just need the 4th button to be on the other row though

Answer (score 0):

You can split into two groups of div:

```
<div container className={classes.root}>
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="Default"
    >
      + Study
    </Button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="Default"
    >
      All Studies
    </Button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="Default"
    >
      Planning
    </Button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="Default"
    >
      Platform
    </Button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="Default"
    >
      Products
    </Button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
      variant="contained"
      color="Default"
    >
      Clients
    </Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use Grid that is one MaterialUi component:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
    <Grid container spacing={3} direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="Default"
        >
          + Study
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="Default"
        >
          All Studies
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="Default"
        >
          Planning
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="Default"
        >
          Platform
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="Default"
        >
          Products
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          style={{ width: "300px", padding: "60px", margin: "15px" }}
          variant="contained"
          color="Default"
        >
          Clients
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </div>
```

You can learn the details from [this link](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) if you want.